# is there anywhere providing world's holidays? [Calendar]

Tags: calendar

I'm going to develop a calendar solution with several languages support, but I'm not sure how I should manage to keep and display all the different holiday info as various country's users need?

is there anywhere providing world's holiday information, so I can just parse and display?
if not, would you recommend a better way to develop so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://qppstudio.net has an up-to-date list of holidays in pretty much everywhere. The free service is restricted to this year, though.

There are two general ways of keeping holidays:

1. Keep them all in a database, and query from there.
2. Compute them, with a rules-based system hard-coded in a class or program.

Both have advantages and drawbacks:

- A database makes it easier to quickly see all you've got. Updates are usually a simple matter. OTOH, depending on the database, "working dates" computations can be slower. Another serious, often overlooked, drawback is that working this way doesn't make it clear why a certain date should be a holiday (other than the fact that "it's/it's not in the table"), so historical errors can pile up real fast (I've seen this happen).
- A class or program is much faster, but updates require modifying source code, recompiling, etcetera. Another advantage (see above) is that a rules-based system tends to make it clear WHY a certain date should be a holiday.

In general, systems that only have to deal with a single country tend to choose mecanism #2, while systems that deal with multiple countries deal tend to go with #1. Personally, I favor #2 as it's faster and makes sure the knowledge of the reasons for a holiday aren't lost.